# Rails filter dependent data through controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Problem: I want to show only upcoming attendances (not past ones) in student/show.

I have

-`scaffold lesson name starts_at:datetime ends_at:datetime`,

-`scaffold attendance student:references lesson:references`,

-`scaffold student name`.

`student has_many :attendances`, `lesson has many :attendances`, `student has_many :lessons, through: :attendances`

I tried

students_controller.rb:

`@future_attendances = @student.attendances.where('lesson.starts_at > ?', Time.now)`

student/show.html.haml:

```
      %table
        %thead
          %tr
            %th Title
            %th Starts at
        %tbody
          - @future_attendances.each do |attendance|
            %tr
              %td= attendance.lesson.name
              %td= attendance.lesson.starts_at
```

But it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: what "doesn't work" about it? does it show past attendances, does the route break, are errors showing etc

Comment: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: lesson.starts_at: SELECT "attendances".* FROM "attendances" WHERE "attendances"."student_id" = ? AND (lesson.starts_at > '2016-04-20 22:07:13.208768')`

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark, can you not just do:

```
@future_lessons = @student.lessons.where('starts_at > ?', Time.now)
```

Then:

```
%tbody
  - @future_lessons.each do |lesson|
    %tr
      %td= lesson.name
      %td= lesson.starts_at
```

Your current code doesn't work because you are looking for a column in the lesson table.  You would need to use the `joins` method to add the lesson table to the query to make that work.  But, again, I think the line above is what you really want.

Comment: @YaroAlexShm Doesn't seem like attendance (the join class) is needed.  Just skip right to the lesson.